# How can i access this body of data in node?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

Here is the data:

```
{
"scope": "read_write" 
"stripe_user_id": "acct_xxxxxxxxx", 
"stripe_publishable_key": "pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxx", 
"token_type": "bearer", 
"refresh_token": "rt_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
"livemode": false, 
"access_token": "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
}
```

that is logged when I do `console.log(body);`

so from there I tried `console.log(body.stripe_user_id);`

came back as `undefined`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where are you getting the data from ? it might need to be parsed. try JSON.parse(body).stripe_user_id

Comment: Your curly braces are in the wrong order

Comment: I see curly braces in the wrong order and a missing comma after the first item. Can you confirm that these errors are not in your program, and if so, edit it in the post?

Comment: And, the quotes around every property name make it look like this might be unparsed JSON.

Comment: @WinterCore thanks, it works but it is in qoutes like so 'xxxx'

Comment: @ooronning im getting this response straight from Stripe. What you see above is just console.log(body);

Comment: @WinterCore nevermind, got it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your body data is not in json formate to do this just parse the body to json and then access the attributes.

```
var body = {
"scope": "read_write",
"stripe_user_id": "acct_xxxxxxxxx", 
"stripe_publishable_key": "pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxx", 
"token_type": "bearer", 
"refresh_token": "rt_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
"livemode": false, 
"access_token": "sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
}

console.log(JSON.parse(body).stripe_user_id);
```